# Any pattern in the following sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

I am practicing finding patterns and sequences with numbers and found one that I cannot seem to find the logic.
$$
\frac{2}{3} ,\frac{4}{3} ,\frac{4}{5} ,\frac{6}{5} ,\frac{6}{7},\frac{6}{8}...
$$
The last term 6/8 breaks my understanding of a possible pattern.
If the last term didn't exist, I could suggest the following.
$$
\frac{2}{3} ,\frac{4}{3} ,\frac{4}{5} ,\frac{6}{5} ,\frac{6}{7},\frac{8}{7},\frac{8}{9},\frac{10}{9}...
$$

Is it possible that the original sequence does not have a pattern with which I can find the nth term?

Answer (score 1):

For
$$\{2,4,4,6,6,6\}$$ there are $27$ sequences in $OEIS$ and for
$$\{3,3,5,5,7,8\}$$ there are $30$ other.

Now, for
$$\frac{2}{3} ,\frac{4}{3} ,\frac{4}{5} ,\frac{6}{5} ,\frac{6}{7},\frac{6}{8}...$$ it is hard to say